# Making an appointment in a public folder calender

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to make an appointment to a calendar called "Schedule". I have only been able to make an appointment to my default calendar.

```
Sub CalendarDemo()
  Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace

  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set items = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("5KW 5030 FIBER SCHEDULE").items

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dimitry i was able to find an answer to my question. First i changed `olFolderCalendar` to `olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders` since the calendar is on the Exchange public folders store. Then i used the `.Folder` method to get to location of the calendar. In my case the calendar is saved under another folder in the public folder store.

```
Sub CalendarDemo()

    Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fl = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders("Subfolder").Folders("calendarName")
        Set objCalAppt = fl.items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
        objCalAppt.Subject = "test"
        objCalAppt.Start = Now
        objCalAppt.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not create a new appointment, you only retrieve the Items collection. Assuming the "Schedule" folder is a suborder of the Calendar folder, the code needs to be

```
  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set item = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("Schedule").items.Add
  item.Subject = "test"
  item.Start = Now
  item.Save
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately this doesnt work  because the folder is not a suborder of the calendar folder.  I was able to find the file path to the calendar ''\\Public Folders - xx@xx.com\All Public Folders\PROFILE CUTTING".

Comment: should i be using `olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders` instead of `olFolderCalendar`

Comment: Yes, and drill down to the folder in question using Folder.Folders("folder 1").Folders("folder 2") etc.